# Align the glossaries' title to the center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries

I saw table of contents and figures titles been aligned to the center with `tocloft` package as follows:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large LISTA DE FIGURAS}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
```

but there isn't a command to center the glossary title.

Comment: Please don't post such fragments only. This depends on the document class too. I think, `glossaries` is wrong here -- you mean the `\listof...` title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tocloft` does only hook into `ToC`, `LoF`,`LoT` and the `\listof...` types that were defined with `tocloft`'s `\newlistof` command.

The `glossaries` package uses `\printglossary[title=...]` to change the optical appearance of the glossary title.

Using `\protect\centering\glossaryname` works for the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}


\newglossaryentry{Foo}{name={Foo}, description={A foobar}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\gls{Foo}

\printglossary[title={\protect\centering\glossaryname}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** After the hint by Nicola Talbot it's better to use a redefinition of `\glossarysection`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][\@gls@title]{%
  \def\@gls@title{#2}%
  \ifcsundef{phantomsection}%
  {%
    \@glossarysection{#1}{\centering#2}%
  }%
  {%
    \@p@glossarysection{#1}{\centering#2}%
  }%
  \glsglossarymark{\glossarytoctitle}%
}
\makeatother


\newglossaryentry{Foo}{name={Foo}, description={A foobar}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\gls{Foo}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian. You're too quick lol. I was still writing a small doc.

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin: You can use that for the next question then ;-)

Comment: I think it would be better to redefine `\glossarysection` rather than putting the formatting commands in the title, otherwise the formatting can end up in the table of contents (if the `glossaries` `toc` option is on).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks, I will update later on